# QtWebKit build error

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I have an `Invalid argument` error when I want to build QtWebKit on Windows.

```
(...) -I"C:\gnuwin32\include" -I"C:\icu\icu\dist\include" -I"." -I"C:\qt-5.3.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o .obj\release\sqlite3.o C:\qt-5.3.0\qtbase\src\3rdparty\sqlite\sqlite3.c
gcc: error: IC:\qt-5.3.0\qtwebkit\Source\WebCore\rendering\svg: Invalid argument
```

I checked the path `C:\qt-5.3.0\qtwebkit\Source\WebCore\rendering\svg` and it is correct.

Do you have a solution ?

Comment: `"C:\qt-.3.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++"` Hmm. Not sure how that got messed up

Comment: Sorry, I made ​​a mistake when I did the copy and paste. The path is `C:\qt-5.3.0\qtbase\mkspecs\win32-g++`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

This line `-I"C:\qt-5.3.0\qtwebkit\Source\WebCore\rendering\style"` in `Makefile.WebCore.Target.Release` file was the cause of the error.

I deleted this line, compiled the sqlite3.cpp file, reinserted it and it resolved the problem.